# Set Image Inline With First

Tags: html, css

How can I set images "LeftSpacer" and "RightSpacer" inline without having a 
 but yet still staying with in the page "Wrapper" I need "LeftSpacer" were it is and "RightSpace" inline with "LeftSpacer" but all the way to the right.

```
<html> 
<head> 

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
  text-align:center; /* for IE */
  margin:0 auto; /* for the rest */
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#Wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
}

div#wrapper {
  text-align:left;
  width:1000px; /* or a percentage, or whatever */
}

    /*End Page Wrapper*/

#Header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.web-designer-ga.com/Pics/top.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
}

#LeftSpacer { 
  width: 14px;
  height: 24px; 
  background: url("http://www.web-designer-ga.com/Pics/btn_lft.gif") no-repeat 0 0; 
}

#RightSpacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: url("http://www.web-designer-ga.com/Pics/btn_rgt.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
}

-->
</style>

</head> 

<body>

  <div id="Wrapper">

    <div id="Header"></div> 

        <div id="LeftSpacer"></div>

        <div id="RightSpacer"></div>

  </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give Leftspacer and Rightspacer a common class, like: `class="spacers"` and then set the css value to `float:right` or `display:inline`

Comment: Make a jsFiddle of it to experiment with

Comment: Shad I tried that and I cant seem to make it work, still stays left with a break.

Comment: I don't get the problem, but when I tried this at jsFiddle right here: http://jsfiddle.net/3zX6R/1/ the rightspacer didn't want to work because you didn't specify a specific height and width, you just made it into height: 100% and width: 100%. I am not sure what you want but I hope I helped :)

Comment: Shad, seems to be OK now I must of had something screwed up.